# Did Islam have point completions during the times of respective prophets?

Tags: sharia, hadith-interpretation, islamic-basis

Quran 5:3 tells the religion is completed.

We cannot assume that Allah gave incomplete religions to followers of prophet Adam, Noah, Ibrahim, musa and eesa.

Does the below report of bukhari support the stand that Islam had point completions during the times of respective prophets or when a major abrogation set was revealed? The final point is Quran and sunnah of last prophet Muhammad (pbuh)

[image]

Bonus question can it be assumed the religion is same from times of first Muslim jinn and only updated by abrogation based on the Quran verse "we have decreed the same religion that we decreed for prophet nuh"?